# Softlayer authentication using openstacknet

Tags: c#, cloud, openstack, openstack-swift

Please, take a look:

```
        var identity = new CloudIdentity
        {
            Username = "user",
            APIKey = "key"
        };

        var cloudIdentityProvider = new CloudIdentityProvider(identity, new Uri("https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/"));
        cloudIdentityProvider.Authenticate(cloudIdentityProvider.DefaultIdentity);
```

It throws UserNotAuthorizedException with message "Unable to authenticate user and retrieve authorized service endpoints"
What is the reason of it?

Thanks.

PS. I use Assembly openstacknet.dll, v1.3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Check the stack trace for the exception. It should give you clue about what is wrong. Also, try to update your client to latest level and check the issue is still reproducible or not. Issue might be due to environment variable or system configuration related. If still facing this issue, you should contact Rackspace support team. Open a ticket against them with detail info.